# UIScrollView tiled subview with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, tiling

I look for this answer everywhere but I couldn't find satisfied answer so far.

I have `UIScrollView` with Tiled `UITableView` as `subviews`. I did it like it was showed in WWDS 2012 video and it work fine. But now I would like to use Auto Layout and I would like to know right and easy solution for this.

Because if I understand Auto Layout correct I can't specify constraints to `subviews` because it will be removed during tiling.

image representation of problem :

[image]

When tiling only one UITableView is on the scroll view, other are stored in NSSet but removed from superview.

But when you start scrolling, UItableView are added to scroll view.

[image]

Comment: can you put a screenshot here!

Comment: It's look like you want to implement some kind of UICollectionView, so better checkout it and do not re-invent the wheel

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is like UICollectionView. I would like to have any number of UITableViews and paging scroller to shift between them.

Comment: Do they have the same type of cells? Cause if they're - it's definitely collection view. And there're plenty of implementation for paging scroller on the Internet=)

Comment: Yes I know there is plenty samples of paging scroller, but I didn't found sample of paging scroller with unknown number of subview with auto layout :D I am little confused. So you say I should implement UICollectionView and do it so big that go offscreen horizontally and than do paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this implementation is obsolete today. Check out `UICollectionView` documentation. And for paging you can find some already implemented solutions too. For example:

http://mobileappdev.learningtree.com/2012/12/13/paging-with-collection-views-part-1/

One more example:

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/

And check out the article from this dude, I like his posts:

http://khanlou.com/2013/04/paging-a-overflowing-collection-view/